# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features', is not working

Tags: python

[image]

My code is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Comment: which version are you using??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-depreciated-how-to-transform-specific-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneHotEncoder categorical\_features depreciated, how to transform specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-depreciated-how-to-transform-specific-column)