# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features' One Hot Encoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to resolve the code above, which I got from Kaggle, but I tried to run it and it throws this error:

> return f(**kwargs)
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

This is the entire code:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv',sep = ',')
print(data.columns);
print(data.isnull().sum())

data['horsepower'] = data['horsepower'].replace('?','100')
print(data['horsepower'].value_counts())

print('O maior MPG é ',data.mpg.max(),'milhoes por galao')
print('O menor MPG é',data.mpg.min(),'milhoes por galao')

f,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,6))
sns.boxplot(data.mpg,ax=ax[0])
sns.distplot(data.mpg,ax=ax[1])

print("Skewness: ",data['mpg'].skew())
print("Kurtosis: ",data['mpg'].kurtosis())

corr = data.corr()
print(corr)

x = data.iloc[:,1:].values
y = data.iloc[:,0].values

lb = LabelEncoder()
x[:,7] = lb.fit_transform(x[:,7])


onehot = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = x)
x = onehot.fit_transform(x).toarray()


xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 0)


sc = StandardScaler()
x = sc.fit_transform(x)


rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 200,random_state = 0)
rfr.fit(xtrain,ytrain)

ypred_rfr = rfr.predict(xtest)
print('Accuracy of the random forest model:',round(r2_score(ytest,ypred_rfr)*100,2),'%')
```

So how can I handle this error?

Comment: Check out the OneHotEncoder scikit-learn docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html - assuming you are using sklearn's class. If you want to include all the features you can just pass x by position, without the parameter name.

Comment: X throws the same error

Comment: OneHotEncoder doesn't take a parameter called `categorical_features`, this is what the error is telling you. Just leave that out of the line where you instantiate the  object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this code, I am not so sure if it makes sense to onehot encode all the columns. Including the numerical ones.

Let's say the aim is to convert the column `car name` to categorical and one hot encode.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

data = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv',sep = ',')
data.columns

Index(['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight',
       'acceleration', 'model year', 'origin', 'car name'],
      dtype='object')
```

As @Jacky1205 has pointed out in the other answer, this function is deprecated. And it will be better to use the data.frames rather than keep them in an array, if you want to use  `ColumnTransformer`. For example:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('one hot', OneHotEncoder(), ["car name"])], remainder="passthrough")
x = ct.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,1:])
```

You can also work at the array level, it can get messy and in this case since your data is not large, you can keep it as a dense matrix:

```
x = data.iloc[:,1:].values
y = data.iloc[:,0].values

lb = LabelEncoder()
x[:,7] = lb.fit_transform(x[:,7])

onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
x = np.concatenate([x[:,:7],onehot.fit_transform(x[:,7].reshape(-1,1))],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated since version 0.20: The categorical_features keyword was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the **ColumnTransformer** instead.

See [Scikit-learn 0.20: sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)  for more details

And this [stack**overflow** question: 54345667](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-depreciated-how-to-transform-specific-column) show how to rewrite with **ColumnTransformer**

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('<Name>', OneHotEncoder(), x)], remainder="passthrough")
ct.fit_transform(x)
```