# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features' How I can solve it?

Tags: python, data-science

I'm working on a Machine Learning course and a I need transform my categorical values. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
LabelEncoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = LabelEncoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,3])

#One Hot encoding o variables dummy. Trata de convertir datos que no son 
#numéricos a datos numéricos de 0 y 1.
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[3])
X = OneHotEncoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

The mistake is with the part of categorical_features, because maybe Python get update to a new version. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because categorical_features was deprecated.

You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.
Here is also ready answer and solution for your question - [OneHotEncoder categorical_features deprecated, how to transform specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-deprecated-how-to-transform-specific-column)