# OneHotEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing following errors here. I have already update all library and im using vscode. But can't findout the solution of the problem.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
y=rooms_df['room type'].values
y_labelencoder = LabelEncoder ()
y = y_labelencoder.fit_transform (y)
y=y.reshape(-1,1)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
Y= onehotencoder.fit_transform(y)
Y.shape
```

it says "OneHotEncoder.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'"
at line code

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
```

can u guys help me to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneHotEncoder categorical\_features deprecated, how to transform specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-deprecated-how-to-transform-specific-column)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library before but I just read that the categorical_features keyword is deprecated.
maybe you will find this answer useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362051/16822178

Comment: Should be a comment or close-vote, not an answer.