# Got " TypeError: OneHotEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features' "

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, one-hot-encoding

I write the following code,
[Here I attached the code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xddYz.jpg)
`from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])`

and it gives me,
TypeError: OneHotEncoder.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

I tried to creating, OneHotEncoder object with keyword argument. But it gives me TypeError

Comment: please dont attach your code as an image, put your code here properly formatted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneHotEncoder categorical\_features deprecated, how to transform specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345667/onehotencoder-categorical-features-deprecated-how-to-transform-specific-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the `init` function for the class does not take a keyword argument with that name.   The documentation says this:

`class sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(*, categories='auto', drop=None, sparse='deprecated', sparse_output=True, dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='error', min_frequency=None, max_categories=None, feature_name_combiner='concat')`

found at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html.